# I have a button that Clears the cells. excel vba I don't want it to trigger the code on a change event

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few cases that trigger on change.
They are working as I wish. If D21 is blank then nothing happens. If anything is in it A message box comes up.etc.

The problem is that I also have a clear Cells button that triggers a change event on D21 when I don't want the message box to come up. Just clear all of the cells.
Here is how I have the cases written.

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back

Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$D$4"
       Me.Unprotect
       'Recalculate Downpayment D5 if Purchase Price is changed

       range("D5").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B5").Value) / 100
       Debug.Print "New value for D5 Downpayment "; range("D5").Value
       range("D6").Value = (range("D4").Value - range("D5").Value) ' This cell won't activate when locked and sheet protected
       Debug.Print "D6 New Mortgage " & range("D6").Value
            Me.Protect
       If range("D21") <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "The Total Mortgaged Amount has changed, The Mortgage Payment Amount (Cell D21) is no longer valid. Please Re-calculate Mortgage with New Amount"
       End If
```

Here is how I have the clear button written

```
Sub ClearTEst()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rRng As range
Dim rCell As range
Dim rRows As range

Set rRng = Sheet1.range("A1:D28")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

If rCell.Locked = False Then
    If rCell <> range("E21") Then

    range("B10") = 5
    range("B14") = 0.4
    range("B15") = 8
    range("B16") = 0.4
    range("B17") = 5
    range("B18") = 5

   ' rCell.ClearContents
   rCell = 0
    End If
End If

Next rCell

End Sub
```

Is there any way to capture that the worksheet change was triggered by the clear button and not trigger the cases that call the message up. First I was thinking that if I could add a condition to the If range("D21") triggered by clear button then no message, if not then message.

Hope this makes sense. thanks

Comment: You can disable/enable event code with `Application.EnableEvents = False` in your Button Code, then set it back to `True`

Comment: You can also use `DoEvents` to manually fire any pending events whilst `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: Macro Man Thank you for this reply. I will keep this in mind. Need to read about DoEvents then.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld  Thanks I used this. It worked but caused another thing that needed the events to work. I managed to bandaide that though. So now all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable your code from triggering events, you need to add the following code before the rest of your code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

' //////////////////////////////
' /// REST OF YOUR CODE HERE ///
' //////////////////////////////

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I just read that I am to avoid comments such as "thanks". Didn't realize that. Wish to thank you. this worked.